# How can I most efficently pull everything from 0x0 to 0x***out of a file with PHP?

Tags: php, file, file-io, fseek

My PHP application involves selecting certain parts of an uploaded file and storing them in my database for easy retrieval. What I need to do is get everything between `0x0` and `0x6A0` (1696 bytes) and store them in the database. It includes binary characters like `NUL` and I'm a bit worried about sanitisation without ruining the file.

I need to do this while making sure that the first 8 bytes of the file are `50 41 52 41`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken straight from fread manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Edited to remove the loop..

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, 1696);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Why loop and add more than 1696 bytes?

Comment: +1 for remembering "b" in `fopen(..., "rb")` in case it's used on a Microsoft Windows system.

Comment: :D Thank you! I'll try this when I have some time tomorrow!
I think the PHP manual should have some "what you can do with this" examples for people searching "How to".

Comment: It works! And I just checked if fread($handle, 8) == "PARA" and it did the trick.